# formatting NSDate object changes the time zone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I get the current NSDate in the user time zone with the following code

```
-(NSDate *)getCurrentDateinLocalTimeZone
{
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate] ;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

return   [dateFormatter dateFromString: [dateFormatter stringFromDate:destinationDate]];
}
```

and at some other point in my app i want to format the date as "HH:mm" for UI purposes so i use the following method

```
-(NSString *)formatDate:(NSDate *)date
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; 
}
```

if the output of the second method is shifted by 3 hours from the result of the 1st method ,,, i only want to change the format of NSDate not the time , what am i doing wrong  ?

Comment: Note that the first routine is NOT formatting/printing the date. And why do you have that last line in the first routine?  Just return `destinationDate`.

Comment: i use the last 3 lines  to format the output

Comment: The last line in the first routine simply converts the date to char form and back to NSDate form -- a no-op.  There is ***no*** format (or timezone) stored in the NSDate object.

Comment: In general (there are always exceptions) one should not modify the GMT offset in an NSDate object, but instead rely on NSDateFormatter to display the date in the correct timezone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getCurrentDateinLocalTimeZone` method adjusts the date for the time zone, formats it using a format string that chops off the time zone, and parses the formatted string back. The resulting `NSDate` is in the UTC time zone (the `+0000` in `2012-07-15 16:28:23 +0000` indicates UTC time). The `formatDate:` method uses `dateFormatter` that is set up for the local time zone, producing a different time. You should set the formatter to use UTC to get the correct time: replace

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

with

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

in the `formatDate:` method.

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work ... here's the output of your solution 
2012-07-15 16:28:23 +0000   // return value of the first method
2012-07-15 16:28:34.037 Links Testing Rassayl[20642:f803] 19:28

Comment: @ahmad -- The first routine isn't formatting the date, nor is it adjusting the timezone.  The NSDate object you get back will show the time in UTC if you NSLog it.

Comment: @HotLicks i log the date before and after the first routine and it does actually change the time and the format of the date

Comment: @dasblinkenlight will this work regardless of the time zone used in the first routine ?

Comment: @HotLicks The first method formats the date and parses it back, so I agree that this is a no-op. Since the log is in UTC, and the OP would like to see the formatted time match the logged time, setting the time zone to UTC in the second method addresses the issue.

Comment: @ahmad `NSDate` objects do not carry time zone information in them, so when you format it in UTC time zone, you get the time with the offset of zero. From the logic of the first method it looks like this is the effect that you are trying to achieve, because you manually adjust the time from your current time zone to UTC by adding the offset.